# What could cause performance issue(s) when using roadie-rails for our case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, html-email

Originally posted as
https://github.com/Mange/roadie-rails/issues/75

We are seeing performance issue for our daily email jobs
By using NewRelic custom instrumentation,
we found out that most time is spent in calling Roadies

Screenshot of our NewRelic data for an example worker:

[image: Time spent for one email job worker]

The integration code:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "rails"
require "action_controller"
require "contracts"
require "memoist"
require "roadie"
require "roadie-rails"

require "new_relic/agent/method_tracer"

module Shared::MailerMixins
  module WithRoadieIntegration
    # I don't want to include the constants into the class as well
    module Concern
      def self.included(base)
        base.extend ClassMethods
      end

      include ::NewRelic::Agent::MethodTracer

      def mail(*args, &block)
        super.tap do |m|
          options = roadie_options
          next unless options

          trace_execution_scoped(
            [
              [
                "WithRoadieIntegration",
                "Roadie::Rails::MailInliner.new(m, options).execute",
              ].join("/"),
            ],
          ) do
            Roadie::Rails::MailInliner.new(m, options).execute
          end
        end
      end

      private

      def roadie_options
        ::Rails.application.config.roadie.tap do |options|
          options.asset_providers = [UserAssetsProvider.new]
          options.external_asset_providers = [UserAssetsProvider.new]
          options.keep_uninlinable_css = false
          options.url_options = url_options.slice(*[
            :host,
            :port,
            :path,
            :protocol,
            :scheme,
          ])
        end
      end
      add_method_tracer(
        :roadie_options,
        "WithRoadieIntegration/roadie_options",
      )
    end

    class UserAssetsProvider
      extend(
        ::Memoist,
      )
      include(
        ::Contracts::Core,
        ::Contracts::Builtin,
      )

      include ::NewRelic::Agent::MethodTracer

      ABSOLUTE_ASSET_PATH_REGEXP = /\A#{Regexp.escape("//")}.+#{Regexp.escape("/assets/")}/i

      Contract String => Maybe[Roadie::Stylesheet]
      def find_stylesheet(name)
        return nil unless file_exists?(name)

        Roadie::Stylesheet.new("whatever", stylesheet_content(name))
      end
      add_method_tracer(
        :find_stylesheet,
        "UserAssetsProvider/find_stylesheet",
      )

      Contract String => Roadie::Stylesheet
      def find_stylesheet!(name)
        stylesheet = find_stylesheet(name)

        if stylesheet.nil?
          raise Roadie::CssNotFound.new(
            name,
            "does not exists",
            self,
          )
        end

        stylesheet
      end
      add_method_tracer(
        :find_stylesheet!,
        "UserAssetsProvider/find_stylesheet!",
      )

      private

      def file_exists?(name)
        if assets_precompiled?
          File.exists?(local_file_path(name))
        else
          sprockets_asset(name)
        end
      end
      memoize :file_exists?

      # If on-the-fly asset compilation is disabled, we must be precompiling assets.
      def assets_precompiled?
        !Rails.configuration.assets.compile
      rescue
        false
      end

      def local_file_path(name)
        asset_path = asset_path(name)
        if asset_path.match(ABSOLUTE_ASSET_PATH_REGEXP)
          asset_path.gsub!(ABSOLUTE_ASSET_PATH_REGEXP, "assets/")
        end

        File.join(Rails.public_path, asset_path)
      end
      memoize :local_file_path
      add_method_tracer(
        :local_file_path,
        "UserAssetsProvider/local_file_path",
      )

      def sprockets_asset(name)
        asset_path = asset_path(name)
        if asset_path.match(ABSOLUTE_ASSET_PATH_REGEXP)
          asset_path.gsub!(ABSOLUTE_ASSET_PATH_REGEXP, "")
        end

        # Strange thing is since rails 4.2
        # name is passed in like
        # `/assets/mailer-a9c96bd713d0b091297b82053ccd9155b933c00a53595812d755825d1747f42d.css`
        # Before any processing
        # And since `sprockets_asset` is used for preview
        # We just "fix" the name by removing the
        #
        # Regexp taken from gem `asset_sync`
        # https://github.com/AssetSync/asset_sync/blob/v1.2.1/lib/asset_sync/storage.rb#L142
        #
        # Modified to match what we need here (we need `.css` suffix)
        if asset_path =~ /-[0-9a-fA-F]{32,}\.css$/
          asset_path.gsub!(/-[0-9a-fA-F]{32,}\.css$/, ".css")
        end

        Rails.application.assets.find_asset(asset_path)
      end
      add_method_tracer(
        :sprockets_asset,
        "UserAssetsProvider/sprockets_asset",
      )

      def asset_path(name)
        name.gsub(%r{^[/]?assets/}, "")
      end

      Contract String => String
      def stylesheet_content(name)
        if assets_precompiled?
          File.read(local_file_path(name))
        else
          # This will compile and return the asset
          sprockets_asset(name).to_s
        end.strip
      end
      memoize :stylesheet_content
      add_method_tracer(
        :stylesheet_content,
        "UserAssetsProvider/stylesheet_content",
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How big is the email being passed into MailInliner?  I would try to breakup the method chain to see if the performance problem is in the 'initialize/new' method or the 'execute' method.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to report my own findings

With NewRelic data, we think most of the time is spent on
`Roadies::Inliner/selector_elements` => `Roadie::Inliner/elements_matching_selector`

And it seems a stylesheet with more style rules will make the style inlining takes longer

[image]

Benchmark code will be something like:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "benchmark/ips"

class TestMailer < ::ActionMailer::Base
  def show(benchmark_file_path:)
    return mail(
      from: "somewhere@test.com",
      to: ["somewhere@test.com"],
      subject: "some subject",
      # This is trying to workaround a strange bug in `mail` gem
      # https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/912#issuecomment-156186383
      content_type: "text/html",
    ) do |format|
      format.html do
        render(
          file: benchmark_file_path,
          layout: false,
        )
      end
    end
  end
end

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.warmup  = 5
  x.time    = 60

  options = Roadie::Rails::Options.new(
    # Use your own provider or use built-in providers
    # I use a custom provider which can be used inside a rails app, 
    # See https://github.com/Mange/roadie for built-in providers
    #
    # options.asset_providers = [UserAssetsProvider.new]
    # options.external_asset_providers = [UserAssetsProvider.new]
    options.keep_uninlinable_css = false
  )

  # Need to prepare html_file yourself with 
  # different stylesheet tag pointing to two different stylesheet files

  x.report("fat") do
    message = ::TestMailer.
      show(
        benchmark_file_path: "benchmark-fat-stylesheet.html",
      ).message.tap do |m|

        Roadie::Rails::MailInliner.new(m, options).execute
    end 

    if message.body.to_s =~ /stylesheet/
      raise "stylesheet not processed"
    end
  end

  x.report("slim") do
    message = ::TestMailer.
      show(
        benchmark_file_path: "benchmark-slim-stylesheet.html",
      ).message

    if message.body.to_s =~ /stylesheet/
      raise "stylesheet not processed"
    end
  end

  # Compare the iterations per second of the various reports!
  x.compare!
end
```